# Capybara not working with factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, factory-bot, minitest

I'm using minitest with factory girl and capybara for integration tests. Capybara works fine when I don't user factory girl to create a user object, like this:

```
it "logs in a user successfully" do
    visit signup_path
    fill_in "Email", :with => "joey@ramones.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "rockawaybeach"
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => "rockawaybeach"
    click_button "Create User"
    current_path == "/"
    page.text.must_include "Signed up!"
    visit login_path
    fill_in "Email", :with => "joey@ramones.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "rockawaybeach"
    check "Remember me"
    click_button "Log in"
    current_path == "/dashboard"
    page.text.must_include "Logged in!"
    page.text.must_include "Your Dashboard"
  end
```

But as soon as I try to create a user with factory girl weird things start happening, such as the visit method and click_button methods stop working. For instance, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this test:

```
require "test_helper"

describe "Password resets" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  it "emails user when requesting password reset" do
    visit login_path
    click_link "password"
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    click_button "Reset my password"
  end

end
```

And here's my factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
    f.password "secret"
    f.password_confirmation "secret"
  end
end
```

Here's the actual error that I'm getting:

```
est_0001_emails user when requesting password reset      0:00:01.624 ERROR
        undefined local variable or method `login_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc2db48d820>:0x007fc2df337e40>
```

But, `visit login_path` works fine if I remove `@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)`

Is this a bug with Capybara? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: what happens if you replace the before block in your testing with let(:user) { Factory(:user) } ?

Comment: That gets the same error. It seems that Capybara is just not submitting the form.

Comment: Is this line a problem? `fill_in "Email", :with => user.email` Shouldn't it be `@user.email`?

Comment: Also, try defining your factory without the `do |f|` and the `f.` prefixes. That doesn't seem to be the standard practice anymore.

Comment: Replacing the before block with `let(:user) { Factory(:user) }` didn't work. Still getting the same problem. I'm having the similar issues on testing the login process as well. I'm going to paste what's going on with that below as I think it might be related. I should have been using `@user.email` with the code above, but that didn't help. I also removed the `do |f|` to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you're requiring the same `test_helper` in both examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work using the DatabaseCleaner gem using `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = truncation`. Here's what I ended up with:

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "minitest/autorun"
require "capybara/rails"
require "active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown"

class IntegrationTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  register_spec_type(/integration$/, self)

  def last_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  end

  def reset_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end
end

class HelperTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown
  include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior
  register_spec_type(/Helper$/, self)
end

Turn.config.format = :outline 

# Database cleaner.
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "email#{n}@example.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
    password "secret"
    password_confirmation "secret"
  end
end
```

**integration/login_integration_test.rb**

```
require "test_helper"

describe "Login integration" do    
  it "shouldn't allow an invalid login" do
    visit login_path
    click_button "Log In"
    page.text.must_include "invalid"
  end

  it "should login a valid user" do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit login_path
    within ".session" do
      fill_in "session_email", :with => user.email
      fill_in "session_password", :with => "secret"
    end
    click_button "Log In"
    page.text.must_include "Logged in!"
    save_and_open_page
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `login_path` and try to use `url`

**for example**

```
visit "/users/login"   #login_path
```