# "Email has already been taken" error with Capybara and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, capybara, factory-bot

I think this could be related to the [issues I described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963095/capybara-not-working-with-factory-girl).

I can't figure out why Capybara is not able to test the sign up form on my rails app when using Factory Girl to create user Factories. I keep getting a `email has already been taken` error. Here's my Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "email#{n}@example.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
    password "secret"
    password_confirmation "secret"
  end
end
```

Here's my sign up test:

```
require "test_helper"

describe "Signup integration" do

  before(:each) do
    visit signup_path
  end

  it "successfully routes to the signup page" do
    page.text.must_include "Sign Up"
  end

  it "signs up a new user" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    fill_in "user_email", :with => user.email
    fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => user.password_confirmation
    click_button "Create User"
    current_path == "/"
    page.text.must_include "Signed up!"
  end  
end
```

And here's my test_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "minitest/autorun"
require "capybara/rails"
require "active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown"

class IntegrationTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  register_spec_type(/integration$/, self)

  def last_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  end

  def reset_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end
end

class HelperTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown
  include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior
  register_spec_type(/Helper$/, self)
end

Turn.config.format = :outline
```

I'm not really sure what could be wrong with that. If I add the Capybara `save_and_open_page` method to each line it is able to get all the way to the password field, but Capybara is not able to fill out the password field. It adds a unique email address like `email3@example.com` to the email field, but then can't add the Factory Girl password. If I put a plain text password into the test (`fill_in "Password", :with => "password")` it is able to fill out the field, but that doesn't seem like the proper way to test this.

I'm also not sure if it could be related to a login test that I have in the app as well? Could the issue be that Capybara is logged in as another user from the login test? If so, how do you clean out the session your tests?

Finally, here's my gemfile, in case that is relevant:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'taps'
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'simple_form'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara_minitest_spec'
  gem 'turn'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Comment: not using databasecleaner? Good practice is to have a well defined state in the database before running tests. Otherwise it is hard to predict the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably in this line

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

try to change it to

```
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
```

The `FactoryGirl.create` creates an instance of User object and saves it to the database. `build` creates an instance, but does not save it to the DB.

Comment: Using `build` in `user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)` fixed the signup test. It makes sense that you could build a user to test the signup process, but my login test is still failing. When using `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` it fails because `email address is already taken`. When I use `user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)` it fails because it isn't able to submit the login form properly. Wouldn't you need to use `create` instead of build to test the login since the user needs to be in the db to login? I'm going to try to add database_cleaner to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

database-cleaner helped me..

gemfile

```
  gem 'database_cleaner'
```

minitest_helper.rb

```
  class MiniTest::Spec
    include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
    before :each do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the same value for the email column which should be unique

Either use `gem fake` or `gem database_cleaner` in the `group :development, test` in your Gemfile.

Fakers allow you to generate random values for your records while `database_cleaner` cleans the database after creating a record